# Julia: Gradation Plotting

Tags: plot, julia, visualization

I try to plot (ReE,ImE) graph, here E = Re[E] + iIm[E] are the complex eigenvalues of a matrix H.
My code is below:

```
eigenvalue,eigenvector = eigen(H)
plot(real.(eigenvalue),imag.(eigenvalue),st = scatter,markersize = 0.2)
```

However, in this code, the plotting is colored by some default color.
I want to plot each (ReE,ImE) by coloring with blue gradation according to the value of the norm of eigenvector of E.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
x = real.(eigenvalue)
y = imag.(eigenvalue)
z = norm.(eigenvector) 
scatter(x,y,marker_z=z, markercolors=:blues)
```

you have to use LinearAlgebra.jl to be able to use the norm function. I assume eigenvector is a vector of vectors

Comment: Great! It helps me a lot. Thank you! P.S. >I assume eigenvector is a vector of vectors. Right. It's my mistake.